# How to pass an environment variable to an AWS Lambda function using the Serverless framework?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, environment-variables, serverless-framework

I am using the aws-node template. I want to do something like this:

```
sls deploy URL='https://postman-echo.com/post'
```

Where **URL** is the environment variable. I am trying to pass this env variable to my *serverless.yml*

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  environment:
    URL: ${env:URL}
```

Then access it in my *handler.js*

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {

  console.log("Lambda invoked\n")

  await axios.post(
    process.env.URL // Accessing the environment variable.
  ).then(function (response) {
      console.log(`Status: ${response.status}`)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(`Error`)
      console.error(error);
    });


  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Function executed successfully!',
      input: event
    }),
  };

};
```

I susspect that the issue is in how I am passing the environment variable to the program but my research has been to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you posted works. You just have to pass URL as an environment variable and NOT as an argument.

This should work (passing URL as an environment variable):

```
$ URL='https://postman-echo.com/post' sls deploy
```

This won't work (you're passing URL as an argument to `sls deploy`):

```
$ sls deploy URL='https://postman-echo.com/post'
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't pass the variable along with the deploy command. Instead set it from the terminal first:

In your terminal, run:

`URL='https://postman-echo.com/post'`

and then run

`sls deploy`

Alternatively, you can use a plugin:

Here's a plguin to that:
https://github.com/colynb/serverless-dotenv-plugin

```
npm i -D serverless-dotenv-plugin
```

then add the plugin to your config file:

```
service: myService
plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
...
```

create your usual dotenv file `.env` and then access as usual:

```
...
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: ${env:STAGE}
  region: ${env:AWS_REGION}
...
```

And if you really need to run it from the console with different urls flags, (though I'd recommend using just one .env file without the command flags) do this:

Put your different urls in:
`.env.url1` `.env.url2` `.env.url3`

and then:

`sls deploy --env url1`

Comment: If running without url flags, would you still need to do sls deploy --env or would sls deploy work?